# How to add column description in CREATE TABLE DDL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ddl

I want to add column descriptions to a table I am creating in BigQuery.

When I try to execute below query:

```
CREATE TABLE mydataset.newtable (
  x STRING(10) "denotes value of x",
  y STRING(10) "denotes value of y",
  z BIGNUMERIC(35) "denotes value of z"
) AS (SELECT x, y, z FROM table2)
```

I get an error:

> Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got string literal "denotes value of x"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#column_name_and_column_schema) this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE mydataset.newtable (
  x STRING(10)     OPTIONS(description="denotes value of x"),
  y STRING(10)     OPTIONS(description="denotes value of y"),
  z BIGNUMERIC(35) OPTIONS(description="denotes value of z")
)
```